# Simulate physical disconnect with Firewalld and firewall-cmd

Tags: mysql, tcp, cmd

I am running a MySQL server in my local network. Multiple client applications, also attached to same network, communicate to this server using MySQL `cppconn` connector. I want to simulate a physical disconnect of the server, and monitor clients' response.

The server is running Fedora 20, equipped with Firewalld and firewall-cmd command line configuration utility.

The simplest is to change the active zone of the firewall to `drop`.

`firewall-cmd --set-default-zone=drop`

This causes TCP SYN to be silently dropped, and clients wait for a timeout. **However, if a client is already connected, then it continues to communicate.**

I am looking for a firewall-cmd example, that will silently drop any active connection, as well as any new TCP SYN. Thus truly simulate a physical disconnect.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think firewall-cmd is an option to simulate that a device physically disconnects. You can try to use --complete-reload which is most likely to terminate active connections, but this will reload firewall completely.

Another option would be to detect the PID of the mysql process and kill it.

```
ps aux | grep mysql
kill -9 pid
```

where pid is the PID of the mysql process.